# Creating exhaustive case columns in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, generate

I am trying to generate a column "Gender Combinations" that creates exhaustive categories of interaction terms like in the table below. Is there an easy way to do this in R?

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| EMP 1 Gender | EMP 2 Gender | Emp 3 Gender | Gender Combinations |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| Male         |              |              | 1 Male              |
| Female       |              |              | 1 Female            |
|              | Male         |              | 1 Male              |
|              | Female       |              | 1 Female            |
|              |              | Male         | 1 Male              |
|              |              | Female       | 1 Female            |
| Male         | Female       |              | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
|              | Male         | Female       | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
| Male         |              | Female       | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
|              | Female       | Male         | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
| Female       |              | Male         | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
| Female       | Male         |              | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
|              | Female       | Male         | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
| Male         |              | Female       | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
|              | Male         | Female       | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
| Male         | Male         | Female       | 1 Male, 1 Female    |
| Male         | Female       | Male         | 2 Males, 1 Female   |
| Female       | Male         | Male         | 1 Female, 2 Males   |
| Female       | Female       | Male         | 2 Females, 1 Male   |
| Female       | Male         | Female       | 2 Females, 1 Male   |
| Male         | Female       | Female       | 2 Females, 1 Male   |
| Male         | Male         | Male         | 3 Males             |
| Female       | Female       | Female       | 3 Females           |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating exhaustive case columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922818/creating-exhaustive-case-columns-in-sql)

Comment: @SMor the link you provided does not refer to [tag:R]

Comment: @Sotos want me to add the `r` tag to the op's self-dupe?

Comment: @MartinZeitler probably not. I have not come across such case before. I 'll see how we handle that and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using the `apply` method with margin 1 to capture rows,

```
dd <- data.frame(V1 = c('M', 'F', '', 'M'), 
                 V2 = c('', 'F', 'M', 'M'), 
                 V3 = c('F', 'M', 'M', ''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dd
#   V1 V2 V3
#1  M     F
#2  F  F  M
#3     M  M
#4  M  M   

apply(dd, 1, function(i){M1 <- sum(i == 'M'); F1 <- sum(i == 'F'); paste0(M1, ' Male', ' ', F1, ' Female')})
#[1] "1 Male 1 Female" "1 Male 2 Female" "2 Male 0 Female" "2 Male 0 Female"
```

**Vectorized Solution**

To avoid the terrible `apply(df, 1, ...)`, you can use `rowSums`, i.e.

```
paste0(rowSums(dd == 'M'), ' Males', ' ', rowSums(dd == 'F'), ' Females')
```